# how to do check if specific column null then ignore some part of query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

how to do check if specific column null then ignore some part of query

I want to get result include these two row, but below query if `user_id` is null then not work

```
SELECT 
  mc.* FROM media_credit mc
  LEFT JOIN credit c ON c.id = mc.credit_id
  LEFT JOIN "user" u ON u.id = mc.user_id
  LEFT JOIN "user" _u ON u.id = c.create_by_user_id
  WHERE mc.media_id = $1
    c.status = $2
    AND u.status = $2   // how to make if mc.user_id is null then dont use this 
    AND _u.status = $2
```

table

```
media_credit
id | media_id | credit_id | username | user_id
1  | 1        | 1         | xx       | null
2  | 1        | 1         | null     |  1

user
id | status
1  | 0

credit
id | status | create_by_user_id
1  | 0      | 32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the other conditions from your `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT mc.* 
FROM media_credit mc
LEFT JOIN credit c 
    ON c.id = mc.credit_id
    AND c.status = $2
LEFT JOIN "user" u 
    ON u.id = mc.user_id
    AND u.status = $2
LEFT JOIN "user" _u 
    ON u.id = c.create_by_user_id
    AND _u.status = $2
WHERE 
    mc.media_id = $1
```

When you filter the *right* tables in the `WHERE` clause, your `LEFT JOIN` will be transformed into an `INNER JOIN`, thus dropping unmatched rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE statement in the where clause ... if mc.user_id is NULL, then $2 = $2 effectively removing the AND clause

```
SELECT 
  mc.* FROM media_credit mc
  LEFT JOIN credit c ON c.id = mc.credit_id
  LEFT JOIN "user" u ON u.id = mc.user_id
  LEFT JOIN "user" _u ON u.id = c.create_by_user_id
  WHERE mc.media_id = $1
    c.status = $2
    AND _u.status = $2
    AND CASE WHEN mc.user_id is NULL THEN $2
        ELSE u.status END = $2
```

Comment: thanks for reply what is then $2 meaning??   does that means if `WHEN mc.user_id is NULL` do nothing ? but why is input a parameter?

Comment: FYI ... I like Felix's answer best.   There is no special meaning to $2.   It was in your original question.   The trick is $2 = $2 or 0 = 0 or 'x' = 'x' so that the AND clause is basically ignored when mc.user_id is NULL.